# Behavior not as expected. Append and Delete row if conditions are met

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script.
The archive part works fine, the delete part is causing issues (but it seems fine when I am using sheet.hideRows).

Here is how it should work:
It should look down Column N then check if the date in Column P is older than 1 month. If yes, append row to 'Archive' sheet and then delete the row.

I've probably missed something quite basic, but I've been looking at it all day and nothing is jumping out at me.
Can someone take a look and figure out why it's not quite right?

**EDIT**: So what it is doing is going deleting rows, but even if they have a ✔ in them. I'm wondering if its getting itself 'confused' by deleting a row and then moving on to the next?

```
// Following script looks at ticked rows that have a date older than 1 month and copies the data to a Archive tab and then deletes the original row.
function archive() {
  var masterSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = masterSS.getSheetByName('IBM / CC / Cisco');
  var archiveSheet = masterSS.getSheetByName('Archive');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = new Date();
  var count = 0
  for ( var r=4; r < data.length; r++) {
    count++
    var row = data[r];
    Logger.log(row[1]);
    if (row[1] == "") { break; }
    if (row[13] == "✔") {
      var date = row[15];
      if (date != "" && ((today.getTime() - date.getTime()) > 2629746000)) {
        Logger.log('actioning row ' + (r + 1));
        archiveSheet.appendRow(row);
        sheet.deleteRows(r+1)
        //sheet.hideRows(r+1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Why do you have a `count` variable? It's not doing anything. Also, what do you mean by, "but even if they have a ✔ in them."? This loop only acts if `row[13]` has a check.

Comment: Can you post an example of the data that you're working with?

Comment: I recommend that you start from the bottom row and work your way up and then you don't have to worry about what rows have already been deleted.

Comment: @I'-'I : I thought that might be the case, thanks for pointing me towards the other script. I'll see if I can peice it together and will update again if I run into other issues or get it working!

Comment: All sorted! Thanks for all your help guys!